# Gradle 3.4 : Build profile using ConfigSlurper

Tags: gradle, groovy, build

I have the below tasks in `build.gradle` and my trying to get the `wsdlURL` value from `config.groovy` as per the environment

```
loadConfiguration()

task printProps << {
    println "WSDLURL:  $config.wsdlURL"
}

def loadConfiguration() {
    def environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'
    System.setProperty('environment', environment)
    println "Environment is set to $environment"

    def configFile = file('config.groovy')
    def config = new ConfigSlurper(environment).parse(configFile.toURI().toURL())
    System.setProperty('config', config) \\line 52
}
```

below is my `config.groovy`

```
environments {
    dev {
        wsdlURL = 'https://dev.com/ts/svs.asmx?wsdl'
    }

    qa {
        wsdlURL = 'https://qa.com/ts/svs.asmx?wsdl'        
    }

    stg {
        wsdlURL = 'https://stg.com/ts/svs.asmx?wsdl'        
    }

    prod {
        wsdlURL = 'https://prod.com/ts/svs.asmx?wsdl'
    }
}
```

And when I run the `gradle -q -Penv=prod printProps` command its failing with below error

```
Environment is set to prod

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'build.gradle' line: 52

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SignService'.
> No signature of method: static java.lang.System.setProperty() is applicable fo
r argument types: (java.lang.String, groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [config,
[wsdlURL:https://prod.com/ts/svs.asmx?wsdl]]
Possible solutions: setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getProperty
(java.lang.String), getProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), hasProperty
(java.lang.String), getProperties(), getProperties()
```

below is my environment details

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-02-20 14:49:26 UTC
Revision:     73f32d68824582945f5ac1810600e8d87794c3d4

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Looks like gradle couldnt set groovy object into system property, can some one please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear

[System.setProperty(key, value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) expects two `String` arguments but you are passing a `String` and a `ConfigObject`.

Perhaps you want to

```
System.properties['config'] = config
```

Or

```
System.properties.put('config', config)
```